# C++ - Error C2568 - Expression must have an integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, enums

This is the inefficient, platform dependent code causing the issue.

```
#define MGE_WARN(X) SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, 10); std::cout << "MONSTER (WARNING): ", X << std::endl; SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, 1);
```

Don't ask why or what this is doing - it is meant to print yellow text to the console and does but I am trying to put it in a define now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
std::cout << "MONSTER (WARNING): ", X << std::endl;
```

with

```
std::cout << "MONSTER (WARNING): " << X << std::endl; 
//                               ^^^^^^
```

Note the change from `,` to `<<`.

Comment: Yes the original code is probably incorrect, but how does this explain the error message? Last I looked the comma operator is alive and well.

Comment: Oh wait, I get it now - it's the second `<<` that generates the error.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that. However - I am now getting another error. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
'Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found Monster Game Engine Core' as well as 'LNK2005 "void * hOut" (?hOut@@3PAXA) already defined in EngineMain.obj Monster Game Engine Core'

Comment: Unless `hOut` is a global that every single place you use the macro will have access to then you're going to have a problem.

Comment: @mattiemonster 1) This problem is completely unrelated to your original question (which is answered). 2) You defined some function/global variable/etc. multiple times. Can't say for certain without more details.

Comment: You might learn the language before you try and use it. :)  My crystal ball says you defined a variable in a header.  This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680065/include-header-file-error-multiple-definition  Or just use `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` instead of `hOut`  That's not the best solution, but if you're already going down the wrong road with the macro...

Comment: This refers to the C language but in this case C and C++ are close enough for rock 'n roll: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c

Comment: Hey, got it working all now! Thanks, everyone :) I'm using the Chernos tutorials. Therefore, I will slowly get better and use more optimized and mainstream methods for these sort of things.